# Uninstall Stock Apps on Motorola Droid!

Tags: motorola-droid, stock-android, uninstallation

I need to know if I can uninstall the following apps without causing any adverse impact on the phone. I have already uninstalled FACEBOOK and TWITTER app.

I am with Verizon and I am planning to uninstall the following.
1) Launcher - I use Go Launcher, so don't see a point in having this.
2) Amazon MP3 - Never used this app. So don't see any point in having it.
3) Car Home - This is an annoyance that I don't need.

So have you uninstalled these apps from your Motorola Droid? Did it cause any issues?

Comment: I would *assume* you need the launcher but the other two aren't needed.

Comment: CarHome is now gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyanogenmod has a [barebones list of apps and the relative safety of uninstalling each](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Barebones).  While it's for CM ROMs, the list will be pretty similiar for the DROID.

FYI, if Verizon ever releases any OTA updates in the future for your phone, they won't install if you don't have the stock apps installed. Usually you're better off 'freezing' them with Titanium Backup.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I have now modded my device and installed the latest available version of Cyanogen Mod. Facebook / Twitter / Amazon MP3 / Car Home no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about Launcher -- some system apps provide services to the OS that 3rd party apps use, rather than replace.  For example, the system's Phone (Dialer), Contact, and Messaging apps generally handle communications with the cellular radio hardware or system DBs for messages/contacts/syncing themselves in ways that 3rd party dialers/messaging apps can't replicate or replace.  The 3rd party apps still end up using the system functionality.

The system *needs* to have a launcher as a system app, even if you've got a 3rd party one in place.  Thought experiment: What would happen if you did a factory reset without restoring the system launcher?

Now, if you can make GO Launcher a system app then you might be able to remove the stock launcher.

Amazon MP3 is pure bloatware if you're not using Amazon's MP3 service.

As you've already discovered, Car Home can also be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your phone needs to be rooted if it isn't yet.

Facebook, Twitter and Amazon MP3 can safely be uninstalled.

I'm not sure about the launcher. If you're not sure either I'd keep it.